# Can't get CFB encryption/decryption to work (probably an endianness issue)

Tags: encryption, cryptography, low-level, zig

I have been trying to implement CFB encryption/decryption in Zig (just testing CFB8 for now) but I keep running in to the same issue:

```
============ expected this output: =============  len: 64 (0x40)

CA 8E B6 37 B5 35 91 85  F1 5E F6 F1 10 E5 21 98  ...7.5...^....!.
7A 9D 9C B3 FA C2 22 76  62 CF C0 94 58 AC B0 5C  z....."vb...X..\
FF B0 71 B5 34 DD FF 3F  6F 7D 0E A8 64 A5 EF 62  ..q.4..?o}..d..b
CA 1D E2 3B 66 F5 18 49  39 24 F7 AE 08 69 D0 96  ...;f..I9$...i..

============= instead found this: ==============  len: 64 (0x40)

8E CA 37 B6 35 B5 85 91  5E F1 F1 F6 E5 10 98 21  ..7.5...^......!
9D 7A B3 9C C2 FA 76 22  CF 62 94 C0 AC 58 5C B0  .z....v".b...X\.
B0 FF B5 71 DD 34 3F FF  7D 6F A8 0E A5 64 62 EF  ...q.4?.}o...db.
1D CA 3B E2 F5 66 49 18  24 39 AE F7 69 08 96 C1  ..;..fI.$9..i...

================================================
```

Now, I almost immediately assumed it was an endianness issue so spent several hours messing with Zig's std lib functions to see how I could make sure it was using the right endian. However, it either got worse or just came back to this. I asked on Zig's discord and they confirmed that it was probably an endian issue as well.

My code is mainly based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23897809/different-results-in-go-and-pycrypto-when-using-aes-cfb/37234233#37234233) go implementation and [this](https://xilinx.github.io/Vitis_Libraries/security/2019.2/guide_L1/internals/cfb.html) visual representation.

Here is my code:

```
pub const CFB_Size = enum(u8) {
    CFB_1 = 1,
    CFB_8 = 8,
    CFB_64 = 64,
    CFB_128 = 128,
};

pub fn CFB(comptime BlockCipher: type, comptime size: CFB_Size) type {
    const block_length = BlockCipher.block_length;

    return struct {
        const Self = @This();

        block: BlockCipher,
        block_length: usize = block_length,
        size: u7 = @truncate(@intFromEnum(size)),
        iv: getBlockSizeInt() = 0,
        cipher_text: getBlockSizeInt() = 0,
        endian: std.builtin.Endian,

        pub fn initByteArray(block: BlockCipher, iv: [block_length]u8, endian: std.builtin.Endian) Self {
            var self = Self{
                .block = block,
                .endian = endian,
            };
            self.iv = mem.bytesAsValue(getBlockSizeInt(), &iv).*;
            return self;
        }

        fn getBlockSizeInt() type {
            return if (block_length == 16) u128 else if (block_length == 32) u256 else u192;
        }

        fn getCfbSizeInt() type {
            return switch (size) {
                .CFB_1 => u1,
                .CFB_8 => u8,
                .CFB_64 => u64,
                .CFB_128 => u128,
            };
        }

        pub fn enc(self: *Self, dst: []u8, src: []const u8) void {
            const src_sections = mem.bytesAsSlice(getCfbSizeInt(), src);
            var dst_sections = mem.bytesAsSlice(getCfbSizeInt(), dst);

            for (0..src_sections.len) |i| {
                self.block.encrypt(mem.asBytes(&self.cipher_text), mem.asBytes(&self.iv));
                // Get new cipher text
                const dst_value = src_sections[i] ^ @as(getCfbSizeInt(), @truncate(self.cipher_text));
                dst_sections[i] = dst_value;
                // Add to iv
                self.iv >>= self.size;
                self.iv |= @as(getBlockSizeInt(), dst_value) << @truncate(block_length * 8 - self.size);
            }
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: It might work to change `dst_sections[i]` to `= std.mem.nativeToBig(getCfbSizeInt(), dst_value)` although that will likely be broken on big-endian architectures.